# Using external CSS on teachable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Made an html and css file and now trying to import them onto teachable which has code snippet sections.

The bootstrap CDN loads, however I hosted my CSS file on my own server and when putting in the source it does not load. Does this have to be done in any particular way?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="netcompass.co.uk/style1.css">
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?  It could be a problem with syntax, a problem with the path, or a problem with your script coming before something that is overriding it.  Without more information, this isn't possible to answer

Comment: Ok, The bootstrap CSS loads, just not mine, which is important.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netcompass.co.uk/style1.css">

Comment: When I take the file source and create a .html on my desktop it works fine! Yet in teachable it does not load at all.

Comment: It's most likely caused by a missing protocol in your URL. Changing it to `href="https://hnetcompass.co.uk/style1.css"` should work. You'll probably need to set up https on your server, since teachable.com is on https too, and most modern browsers will [refuse to load](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content) "insecure" (plain http) resources. It's free and easy these days with letsencrypt.org. [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) would probably be the easiest way (they have docs even for Apache, which your server seems to use).